# error: no match for 'operator>>' (operand types are 'std::basic_istream<char> cin>> salary >> endl; ^

Tags: c++

I have following code:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int salary;
    int childeren;
    cout << "please type base salary=";
    cin>> salary >> endl;
    cout<< "plz type count your childeren=";
    cin >> childeren >> endl ;
    int Totalsalary=salary + childeren*10;
    cout<< Totalsalary<< endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to understand creating error:

> no match for 'operator>>' (operand types are 'std::basic_istream::__istream_type {aka std::basic_istream}' and '')
>      cin>> salary >> endl;
>                   ^

Comment: `cin>> salary >> endl;` omit the `endl`.

Answer (score 6):

`std::endl` is meant for creating end of line and flushing stream buffer. It supposed to be use with `std::cout` not with `std::cin`.

So correct your following line

```
cin>> salary >> endl;
```

to

```
cin>> salary;
```